# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar evento de un TD de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Buen día, mi problema es tengo un TD de una tabla donde contiene una imagen con un evento, tuve que mover un poco la imagen para que se ajustara con top y left de css, la imagen es  solo un punto, entonces al pasar el mouse por un lado de la tabla activa el evento, y lo que quiero es que solamente el evento se active al pasar el mouse en la imagen.
Este es mi código de mi TD. Me podrían apoyar por favor, no doy como resolverlo o mas bien si es posible.

```
<td rowspan="7" colspan="4"  > 
 <a class="lizatom-tooltip-top lizatom-tooltip-light-gray delay-0" href="detallecentros.asp?cec=9040" onmouseout="MM_swapImgRestore();" onmouseover="MM_swapImage('MapaRedAtencion_r86_c961','','MapaRedAtencion/img/MapaRedAtencion_r86_c96_s2.gif',1)">
<img style="position:relative; top:-9px; left:4px;" name="MapaRedAtencion_r86_c961" src="MapaRedAtencion/img/MapaRedAtencion_r86_c96.gif" width="9" height="9" id="MapaRedAtencion_r86_c961" alt="" border="0" />
<span><img src="MapaRedAtencion/images/9821F.jpg" alt="" title="" border="0" />CIJ Guanajuato<br/><br /><p class="more-link">Ver más</p></span>
</a>
</td>
```

Comment: si lo haces con JQuery redefine el evento y listo.

Comment: así no se puede replicar... A poder ser comparte tu JS también

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con JQuery y redefinir el evento, pero vacío. Algo así:

```
$(tuSelector).attr("onmouseover", "");
```

Esto redefine el atributo `onmouseover` a vacío, por lo tanto el evento quedara anulado.

Esta no es la mejor manera, pero es la que te casa mejor.

Para otras ocasiones puedes usar `.bind(evento)` y `.unbind(evento)`, que se utliza para esto mismo.

Te dejo unos enlaces con + info.

https://api.jquery.com/bind/

https://api.jquery.com/unbind/